# Bootstrap Within an iFrame

Tags: iframe, bootstrap-4

Hope this is right place to ask this.

We have a 3rd party company that provides content on our website via an iFrame. It's loading incredibly slowly (may be down to many factors I know).

Question is, does using Bootstrap to create this 'page within a page' make the load time any longer or would it be purely down the fact it's an iFrame that loads after the page has loaded? Would using any other language to serve the content inside the iFrame create a faster experience?

To the user this is so slow it's causing people to leave!

Comment: Bootstrap isn't a language. I'm not sure what you mean by "using Bootstrap to create this 'page within a page'". Do you have a live link?

Comment: I've actually resolved this now by creating it from scratch with good old html/css instead of using this companies bootstrap template.

Answer (score 0):

I have used iFrame in web apps that use bootstrap and I haven't seen a problem with the iframes loading and this was a frame with realtime data. The way I was using bootstrap was via a cdn. Also, If I try to see the website in the current corporation I work for the website and the iframe overall take longer to load due to all the security filters we have